# Why does setBounds() method not work even after setting setLayout() as null?

Tags: java, swing

Usually setBounds() method positions the called object in the specified location and in specified size..right?
I created a JFrame class and demonstrated its working on a button with setting setLayout(null).
Then I created a class which extends JPanel and put some components in it.
The Bounds for these components are set inside a method.
An object of this class is included in a class which extends JFrame.
Then this object calls setBound() method.
But the result does not show the components in JPanel extended class.
the cde fragment is given below.

```
class Administrator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
  public Administrator()
  {
    setTitle("Administration"); 
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);    
    JButton newbutton=new JButton(" New.. ");
    newbutton.addActionListener(this);
    add(newbutton);
    newbutton.setBounds(100,100,100,25);
    setVisible(true);

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
      new Administrator();
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
    String act=(String)ae.getActionCommand();
    if(act.equals("New Registry..")||act.equals(" New.. "))
     {
        regPanel rgpnl=new regPanel();

        Dimension sz;
        sz=rgpnl.getPreferredSize(); 
        rgpnl.setBounds(800,800,sz.width,sz.height);       
        rgpnl.arrangeComponents();   
        add(rgpnl);


        repaint();
        setVisible(true);
     }
}
class regPanel extends JPanel 
{
  Label namelab;
  JTextField name;
  JButton do_register;
  public regPanel()
  {
    //Container   = get ();
    setLayout(null);

    namelab=new Label("Name :");
    name=new JTextField(20); 
    add(namelab); 
    add(name);
    add(do_register); 
   }
   public void arrangeComponents() 
  {
    Dimension size;

    size=namelab.getPreferredSize();
    namelab.setBounds(20,10,size.width,size.height);
    name.getPreferredSize();
    name.setBounds(150,10,size.width,size.height); 
    do_register.setBounds(10,10,size.width,size.height);

    repaint();

  }    
}
```

Comment: You are missing a couple of `}`'s and imports in your code to make it truly paste-compile-run worthy.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from some questionable parts of your code -- like missing curly brackets, null pointers and such errors -- your code creates components at (800,800) while the interface is only 500x500 px in size. This will put the components out-of-view. Put the components at a smaller offset from the window origin and they will show. (I tested this, along with some modifications to your code, like the order in which calls are made with respect to `setLayout(null)`. This call should seemingly occur at the right time, otherwise the components wouldn't show for me.)

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you want to hear, but you're far better off avoiding use of null layout and absolute positioning as it can be a bear to maintain, and may make your GUI ugly or unusable if run on an OS other than the one it was developed on.  Most GUI's, even fairly complex GUI's can be made with a nesting of JPanels each using a simple layout manager, or barring that GridBagLayout or MIgLayout (not part of standard Java, but free when I last used it, and fairly easy to use).  Also, if you show us an image of the layout you're trying to achieve, or describe it in fairly good detail, we can help guide you on the best layout manager combinations to try first.